# prefix classes in angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using angular ui-select dropdown in my website. The theme I am using is selectize. During run time the elements are prefixed with either **ui-select** or **selectize**. Since I already have the styles existing for one page, the new select dropdown also takes the same styles. Is it possible to prefix the classes so that i can have different styles for each pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible to prefix the classes as you say, but you could use descendant css selectors to separate your styles.

```
.someContainerClass .ui-select {  }
```